# Pong game is running too fast with FPS counter

Tags: java, performance, timer, frames, frame-rate

I have a Pong game with an FPS counter but I have a few problems. I want the FPS counter to NOT be limited at 60 FPS, I want the FPS counter to go as high as it can.

The FPS is currently working but the problem is that the game is running REALLY fast, I want the game to always run at a speed that is playable. I tried adding a timer for 5 ms but that caused the FPS counter to not work properly.

I want the FPS counter to NOT be limited at 60 FPS but at the same time use some sort of timer. Here is my code:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

// Lite variabler
JFrame frame;
int windowWidth, windowHeight;
Point bollXY;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
Image bildPaddel;
Image bildBollen;
int paddelY;
int paddel2Y;
boolean paddelUp, paddelDown;
Random rand;
int score, score2;
boolean bollUp, bollRight, changeDirection;
int fruktDistansRand;
long time;
int fps, newfps;
int fpsTimesCounter;

// Konstruktor
public Main(){
    // Definera variabler
    frame = new JFrame();
    bildPaddel = new ImageIcon("src/images/Player.png").getImage();
    bildBollen = new ImageIcon("src/images/Pong.png").getImage();
    bollXY = new Point(673, 352);
    paddelY = 312;
    paddel2Y = 312;
    paddelUp = false;
    rand = new Random();
    score = 0;
    score2 = 0;
    bollUp = false;
    bollRight = false;
    changeDirection = false;
    fruktDistansRand = 0;
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fps = 0;
    newfps = 0;
    fpsTimesCounter = 0;

    // Lyssnare
    frame.addKeyListener(this);

    // Bygga fönstret

    frame.add(this);

    // Obligatoriska egenskaper
    frame.setTitle("Pong");
    frame.setSize(1366, 724); // Eftersom spelet inte ska vara helt i fullskärm sätts fönstret på 1366x724 så att aktivitetsfältet syns
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centrerar fönstret
    frame.setResizable(false);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    bollUp = true;
    bollRight = true;
    changeDirection = false;
    bollXY = new Point();

    frame.add(this);
}
// Metoder
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(bildBollen, bollXY.x, bollXY.y, null);
    g.drawImage(bildPaddel, 50, paddelY, null);
    g.drawImage(bildPaddel, 1300, paddel2Y, null);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100));
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(score2 + "", 1002, 100);
    g.drawString(score + "", 314, 100);

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000){
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = newfps;
        newfps = 0;
    }
    else{
        newfps++;
    }
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString(fps + "", 5, 22);

    update();
}

public void AI(){

    fruktDistansRand = rand.nextInt(200) + 950;
    if(bollXY.x > fruktDistansRand && bollXY.x < 1380 && bollRight && paddel2Y > 0 && paddel2Y < 596){
        if(paddel2Y + 50 < bollXY.y){
            paddel2Y = paddel2Y + 3;
        }
        else{
            paddel2Y = paddel2Y - 3;
        }
        if(paddel2Y <= 0){
            paddel2Y = paddel2Y + 3;
        }
        if(paddel2Y >= 596){
            paddel2Y = paddel2Y - 3;
        }
    }
}

public void ifUp(){
    if(bollUp){
        if(changeDirection){
            if(bollXY.y < 0){
                bollUp = false;
            }
            else{
                bollXY.y = bollXY.y - 3;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(bollXY.y < 0){
                bollUp = false;
            }
            else{
                bollXY.y = bollXY.y - 3;
            }
        }
    }

    else{
        if(changeDirection){
            if(bollXY.y > 675){
                bollUp = true;
            }
            else{
                bollXY.y = bollXY.y + 3;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(bollXY.y > 675){
                bollUp = true;
            }
            else{
                bollXY.y = bollXY.y + 3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void update(){
    if(paddelUp){
        if(paddelY > 0){
            paddelY = paddelY - 3;
        }
    }
    if(paddelDown){
        if(paddelY < 596){
            paddelY = paddelY + 3;
        }
    }

    if(bollRight){

        if(bollXY.x > 1290 && bollXY.x < 1300 && bollXY.y < paddel2Y + 100 && bollXY.y > paddel2Y-20){

            if(!bollUp && bollXY.y < paddel2Y){
                changeDirection = true;
                bollUp = true;
            }
            else if(bollUp && bollXY.y > paddel2Y + 80){
                changeDirection = true;
                bollUp = false;
            }

            bollRight = false;
        }
        else if(bollXY.x > 1600){
            score++;
            bollXY.y = rand.nextInt(690);
            bollXY.x = 678;
        }
        else
            bollXY.x = bollXY.x + 3;

        ifUp();
    }
    else{
        if(bollXY.x > 50 && bollXY.x < 60 &&bollXY.y < paddelY + 100 && bollXY.y > paddelY-20){
            if(!bollUp && bollXY.y < paddelY){
                changeDirection = true;
                bollUp = true;
            }
            else if(bollUp && bollXY.y > paddelY + 80){
                changeDirection = true;
                bollUp = false;
            }
            bollRight = true;
        }
        else if(bollXY.x < -244){
            score2++;
            bollXY.x = 678;
            bollXY.y = rand.nextInt(596);
        }
        else
            bollXY.x = bollXY.x - 3;

        ifUp();
    }
    AI();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    update();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        paddelUp = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        paddelDown = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        paddelUp = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        paddelDown = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a semantic issue; if the game is not redrawing anything faster than 60fps, why should the counter display something higher?

Comment: Don't call update from paintComponent. Not sure what you're trying to do in that method. It should have instructions on how to paint the panel, nothing else.

Comment: I'm confused, why would you want the fps to be different from the actual rate the frame is updated? In any case you want to update the game state seperately from the repaint, otherwise they are tied to the same interval or make the movement based on time elapsed rather than fixed. I wouldn't see much benefit in repainting as fast as possible, it's not necessary.

Comment: @DerekBrown I know but I want the game to be playable but at the same time show the amount of FPS that the computer can handle. I suppose this can be fixed by making the game skip frames instead of slowing down or running faster. I'm pretty new to programming though so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @J.Doe but that makes no sense.  the only way of knowing how many frames the game to handle is to repaint at that speed, but you won't be doing that.  You are trying to measure something without measuring it...

Comment: @d.j.brown I want the game to show as high FPS as the computer can handle because I'm doing a sort of benchmark which language can have the highest FPS.  And where do you recommend it should update instead of the repaint? I'm relatively new to programming so I know the program is not perfect.

Comment: @DerekBrown Is there no way of having the game at a playable speed and at the same time not limiting the FPS? In modern computer games, when the FPS is over 60, the game is not exactly running faster, it's running at the exact same speed, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @J. Doe if you want something to move by p pixels every t milliseconds then you should either set a timer that updates the positions every t milliseconds separately from repainting, or use the system time and increase the positions by p pixels when a minimum time has elapsed, keeping track of the last time it was updated.

Comment: @J. Doe this is also a prime example of why the logic/state/model should be separate from the view itself. Trying to merge both together is not good software design, the view should just display components/draw based on the state of the model, it shouldn't also have the logic/state. This decoupling also means that you don't need to re-implement game logic for a different interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your game is running really fast, because you use a static increment in each cpu cycle. If you run this program on an slow cpu, your game will run slower. If you run it with a fast cpu your game will run faster.

cpu 1: 100 cycles per second: your ball will move 300 units per second.

cpu 2: 2000 cycles per second: your ball will move 6000 units per second.

When you capped your game at 60 fps, you avoided that issue, because the update will only happen 60 times per second and not 100 or 2000 times.

Another option is to involve time.
This means you measure the time since the last frame and use it as an multiplicator. The faster your cpu runs the lower your time between frames will be. Your ball will move acording to you time. If your your cpu is slower the time between your frames increases and the ball will move further.

```
float delta = // time between your frames
pulic void update(float delta){
...
bollXY.y -= delta * 3;
```

Alternatively a great article for game loops: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/